# Remove title New Products from Magento 2 Content New Products Widget

Tags: magento2, products, widget, new-products

I have scoured the internet looking for a solution of removing the title word `New Products` that exists just above the grid from the Magento 2 new products content widget.

Not sure how to accomplish this. I've seen lots of information about changing xml templates but i'm not skilled enough in Magento to understand what they are saying.

Answer (score 1):

override `items.phtml` file from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml

to your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Now, For title change you can replace `New Products` with **your title** in `case 'new':` like `$title = __('Your Title');`

```
case 'new':
    if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
        $type = 'new';
        $mode = 'grid';
        $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

        $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

        $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
        $title = __('New Products'); //Change this to the title you want
        $items = $exist;

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;
```

and to remove it, just wrap lines 165 to 167 in if condition same as below,

```
<?php if($type != 'new'):?>
    <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title; ?></strong>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml` in your custom theme at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml` and remove the title block/div present on line number 35.

```
<div class="block-title">
   strong role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the location i copy this file to?

Comment: @jkushner please refer updated answer.